# How to update table with value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables nol_art and #tmpIzm I want to update nol_art with value from table #tmpIzm if it's not null otherwise the value stays unchanged
The code that I wrote, but there are some mistake, so it does not work:

```
update nol_art
    set 
        CENA_IZM=if(xd.IZM IS NULL,' ',xd.IZM)
    from
        #tmpIzm xd
        join nol_art a on a.ART_ID=xd.ID_ART
    where 
        a.ART_ID=xd.ID_ART
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
update nol_art 
    set  
        CENA_IZM=coalesce(xd.IZM, CENA_IZM) 
    from 
        #tmpIzm xd 
        join nol_art a on a.ART_ID=xd.ID_ART 
    where  
        a.ART_ID=xd.ID_ART
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it in DB2

```
UPDATE 
        document
    SET 
        department =    
            (SELECT departmentId
                FROM 
                department
            WHERE 
                document.base_child = document.base_child AND
                document.folder_child = document.folder_child)
    WHERE
        EXISTS 
        ( SELECT * FROM department 
                    WHERE department.base_child = department.base_child 
                     AND  department.folder_child = department.folder_child);
```

hope to help